launch an application(or a screen) from flutter background service
I would like to create a service that will run in the background and whose purpose is to detect a ShakeDetector event (check if the User shakes his phone). After detecting the “Shake” event, I'd like to launch the application on a specific page. But I'm having trouble with the context not being valid in a service.
what to do please.
thanks in advance
Thats my code
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:alertcontacts/ui/screens/sos_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter_background_service/flutter_background_service.dart';
import 'package:shake_detector/shake_detector.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:navigator/navigator.dart' as navigator;

Future<void> initializeService() async {
  final service = FlutterBackgroundService();

  await service.configure(
    androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
      onStart: onStart,
      autoStartOnBoot: true, // Démarrage automatique sur Android
      autoStart: true, // Démarrage automatique sur iOS
      isForegroundMode: false,
    ),
    iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
      autoStart: true, // Démarrage automatique sur iOS
      onBackground: onIosBackground,
    ),
  );
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<bool> onIosBackground(ServiceInstance service) async {
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await preferences.reload();
  final log = preferences.getStringList('log') ?? <String>[];
  log.add(DateTime.now().toIso8601String());
  await preferences.setStringList('log', log);

  return true;
}

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
  ShakeDetector.autoStart(
      onShake: () async {
        log('Shake detected!');
      }
  );
}


I'd like to listen to a Shake event from my phone, once the event is captured, launch the flutter application on the SosScreen page.
Event capture is done in background via flutter background service.
Event capture works very well in the background.

Just an idea, have you checked if you could use the local_notification package to start your app by triggering a notification from your backend service?
also in the docs is stated that you can use the invoke function to exchange data.

Thank you, I'll check and get back to you.

I display a notification in the Shake() event that redirects to the application, but when I click on it, it always goes to the home page (and the login page if the user isn't logged in).
When I'm already in the application, I open the SosScreen page via the event and notification.
Here's the function:
onShake: () async {
log('Shake detected!');
NotificationService.showNotification(title: 'SOS', body: 'SOS', payload: {
'sos': 'true'
});
}

do you have the needed handler in your app that will be called when the app is opened via a notification?
